# Pushforward of dual

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $p\colon X=\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ be the projection onto the first factor and $\mathcal{G}$ be a coherent sheaf flat via $p$, such that $p_*\mathcal{G}\cong\mathcal{O}(m_1)$ and $p_*\mathcal{H}\mathit{om}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{O}_{X})\cong\mathcal{O}(m_2)$ for some $m_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Here everything is non-derived.

What can we say about the integers ? Do we expect $m_1m_2\leq 0$ or some formulas involving $m_1,m_2,n$?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but should not the title be "pushforward of dual" rather than "dual of pushforward"?

Comment: Welcome new contributor. There is no such restriction, at least when $n>1$.  Let $s$ be a section of $p$, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the ideal sheaf of the image of $s$.  Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the direct sum of $s_*\mathcal{O}(m_1)$ and the tensor product of $\mathcal{I}$ with the pullback $p^*\mathcal{O}(-m_2).$